# Ionic2 hamburger menu links not working

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm changing root page with this.nav.setRoot(page2) but when i open hamburger menu in page2 the link inside hamburger menu is not working.

Problem is only occurs when i open modal & then navigate the page. 
Modal is open with

```
import {SignInPage} from '../sign-in/sign-in'; 
let signInModal = Modal.create(SignInPage); 
this.nav.present(signInModal);
```

& navigation from modal to another page

```
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';
this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
```

Comment: Post some code for more information. Do you get an error? page2 is an actual static of the page or is it a variable?

Comment: @misha130 I has updated the question you can check.

Comment: You are presenting a modal. So there is top layer of modal. Always on top. Then you switch root which is behind the modal. So you don't see change. First call dismiss on modal and then set new root